# Script to remove nullbytes from machine code?

Tags: assembly, low-level, shellcode

I created some machine/shellcode and when running it nothing happens. It works with other shellcode so it must be a problem with my shellcode. It contains NULL bytes and I read that a program crashes when there is a null byte. From using msfvenom I know that it has a function to remove nullbytes. My code isnt from msfvenom but it means there must be a way to remove NUll bytes with a script, rigth?
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The null bytes in your code have a purpose; you cannot simply remove them. They are only a problem if you rely on C strings and strcpy to get your shellcode into a victim program.

Comment: I know that. They have to be replaced with similar code that doesnt produce NULL bytes. I am using the shellcode of a c++ program and I am running it through the same language. As the code is long it has a lot of NULL bytes. Any tips to remove them?

Comment: @Marvlogs You need to manually go through the code and replace each instruction that contains a NUL byte with one that doesn't.  Get your assembler to generate a program listing; it helps finding the NUL bytes.  This is generally a process that requires experience and knowledge about the CPUs instruction set.

Comment: @fuz: you could imagine some automated rules like turning `mov reg, imm32` into `push imm8` / `pop reg`, or into `mov reg, val + 0x11111111` / `lea reg, [reg - 0x11111111]`.  Or a `[reg + disp32]` addressing mode because you need more than +-8-bit.  I guess possibly `add` a biased constant into the register then subtract the bias and then after using the address restore the original...  But this could easily get super bloated.  And can't handle everything.  e.g. in a forward `jmp` or `call` that goes farther than 127 bytes isn't obvious how to automate.